# Convert Array to json using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, multidimensional-array

I am Trying to convert array to json but not getting exact result I am looking for.

Here,

```
<?php
      $result=array();
      $result[status]=1;
      $data=array(
                array("ucode" => "123","name" => "abc","lname" => "xyz"),
                array("ucode" => "431","name" => "cdb","lname" => "zsa")
              );
      foreach($data as $res){ 
          $data=array();
           $data[ucode]=$res['ucode'];
           $data[name]= $res['name'];
           $data[lname]= $res['lname'];
           $result[content]=$data;
        }

echo $res=json_encode($result);

?>
```

Actul Result:

```
{"status":1,"content":{"ucode":"431","name":"cdb","lname":"zsa"}}
```

My expected Result:

```
{"status":1,"content":[{"ucode":"123","name":"abc","lname":"xyz"},{"ucode":"431","name":"cdb","lname":"zsa"}]}
```

please, Guide me where is mistake, not getting the expected result.

Comment: MAYBE Because of the multiple syntax errors in that code

Comment: @jeroen ok let me try thank you

Comment: @jeroen , working perfect  Thank you

Comment: You should really quote the strings you are using as keys by the way...

Comment: Or just `$result = ['status' => 1, 'content' => $data ];`

Comment: @NigelRen And wrapp a `json_encode()` round that and Bob's yer Uncle

Comment: Why are you looping over an array to build EXACTLY that same array again?

Comment: Then also why are you destroying the array `$data` that you are looping over in the first line inside the foreach loop?

Comment: foreach Yes, data with rename name like name to nme or lname just lnme,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why need loop, if you can directly push data into content index of result.

```
$result         = [];
$result["status"] = 1;
$data           = [
    ["ucode" => "123", "name" => "abc", "lname" => "xyz"],
    ["ucode" => "431", "name" => "cdb", "lname" => "zsa"],
];
$result['content'] = $data;
echo $res = json_encode($result);
```

Short form of it,

```
$result = ['status' => 1, 'content' => $data];
echo json_encode($result);
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79d6577693b09c79a5655fa28dfd001feb06f5ae).

**Output**

```
{"status":1,"content":[{"ucode":"123","name":"abc","lname":"xyz"}, 
 {"ucode":"431","name":"cdb","lname":"zsa"}]}
```

Comment: Working perfectly for me

Comment: I think as the original answer did not have any explanation with it was (I think) the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your reusing the variable `$data` which is causing your problem. Also when you append to the `$result['content']` array, you need to use `[]`.

```
<?php
    $result = array(
        'content' => array(),
        'status' => 1
    );
    $data= array(
        array("ucode" => "123","name" => "abc","lname" => "xyz"),
        array("ucode" => "431","name" => "cdb","lname" => "zsa")
    );
    foreach($data as $res){ 
        $tmp = array(
            'ucode' => $res['ucode'],
            'name' => $res['name'],
            'lname' => $res['lname']
        );
        $result['content'][] = $tmp;
    }
    echo $res = json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: What is the need of loop in your code, can you explain?

Comment: @quickSwap There is no need. But I suspect this is not exactly what the OP is trying to do in their original code. It's probably a simplified version.

Comment: Yes but the actual code probably is not like that. I suspect the `$data` is just for our benifit. It's probably coming from a database or some other source. Either way, if the OP is actually just looping over the same data pointlessly then the other answers are showing he doesn't need to do that. I'm just showing another point of view.

Comment: Yes, It is coming from database

Answer (score 0):

I got another way solution, just with you guys,

because I want rename my variables names when pass in api with json_encode().

```
  <?php
            $result=array();
            $result['status']=1;
            $data=array(
                      array("ucode" => "123","name" => "abc","lname" => "xyz"),
                      array("ucode" => "431","name" => "cdb","lname" => "zsa"),
                    );
            $ar=array();
            foreach($data as $res){
                $data=array();
                 $data['u_code']=$res['ucode'];
                 $data['u_name']= $res['name'];
                 $data['u_lname']= $res['lname'];
                 $ar[]=$data;
              }
            $result['content']=$ar;
            echo $res=json_encode($result);

      ?>
```